# Jekyll Markdown, compiling images with paragraph tags

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

This is just a simple problem but it's one that I can't find on Google to solve this. Basically what is happening is that I have a Jekyll website, and I'm using kramdown for the markdown compiling.

When I add an image to a markdown file like below:

```
![Image Alt Tag](path/to/image)
```

It will compile it with a `<p>` tag when I don't want it to as seen below.

```
<p><img src="path/to/image" alt="Image Alt Tag" /></p>
```

This is how I would like the markdown file to compile with an image tag

```
<img src="path/to/image alt="Image Alt Tag" />
```

I am wondering where I'm going wrong or why Jekyll is compiling the images with paragraph tags.

Thanks in advance

**---Edit: Tried another way but ended up with the same problem**

I have tried this with only adding the `html` code which would be below:

```
<img src="path/to/image" alt="Image Alt Tag" />
```

and it would still compile with adding `<p>` tags as seen below.

```
<p><img src="path/to/image" alt="Image Alt Tag" /></p>
```

I am wondering why the markdown file is still adding `<p>` tags to html code when it is not needed?

Comment: some clues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456010/in-markdown-is-there-a-way-to-stop-images-from-being-wrapped-with-p-tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [David Jacquel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548376/david-jacquel) for putting me on the right path.

It seems that an image is an inline element and that if Markdown detects an image that is not inside a block element such as `<figure></figure>`, `<div></div>` or other similar block elements then it will apply a `<p></p>` tag to wrap around the image.

To see how Markdown compiles the document, I have found that [Babelmark 2](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/) is an useful resource and worth trying out to see if the markdown compiler that you are using is doing what you want it to do.

Here is an [example](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=!%5Bimg%20alt%5D(path%2Fto%2Fimage.png)%0A%0A%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22path%2Fto%2Fimage.png%22%20alt%3D%22img%20alt%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E) of what I used Babelmark 2 to figure out after the pointing out by [David Jacquel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548376/david-jacquel) on this particular problem.

I hope this will help whoever has come across the same problem, and did not notice that it was an inline/block element issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to include an image tag without the surrouding paragraph?

Comment: Yes, by using block elements like `<figure>`, or a simple `<div>` would do to enclose the image. Otherwise Markdown will treat it as inline and include `<p>` tags then.

Answer (score 1):

This is a repost of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456010/in-markdown-is-there-a-way-to-stop-images-from-being-wrapped-with-p-tags/41528319#41528319), where I use a partial to cover all of a blog's image needs.

As other's have said, images are inline elements and Markdown parsers will force them to be wrapped in block level elements. The currently accepted answer is hacky: it looks messy in your markdown, is not robust/extensible, and is not easily modifiable. I use Middleman for my blog and created a partial for my images that does everything I could want an image to do. I assume/hope Jekyll has partials as well and that this answer, although varying from Jekyll in syntax, will still be relevant to you.

Note that I prefix my image links if they don't begin with "http://", "https:/" or "/". This is because I have a solid organizational structure for my blog's images, and makes it simpler when using this partial, I just need the image name and no other parts of its path.

Here is the partial:

`partials/_image.erb`

```
<%
#initialize local variables in case they were not included
caption ||= ""
alt ||= ""
classes ||= ""

#strip '.html' extension off article link to get name of folder
url = current_article.url
url_without_ext = url[0..url.length-6]

#determine if image has an exact link or belongs to "/images/blog/CURRENT_ARTICLE_NAME/"
prefix = src[0..6]
if prefix != "http://" and prefix != "https:/" and src[0] !="/" then
  #image belongs to "/images/blog/CURRENT_ARTICLE_NAME/" - add prefix to src
  src = "/images#{url_without_ext}/#{src}"
end
%>

<!-- Use Kramdown's 'nomarkdown' tag so that this figure is not wrapped in a 'p' tag in the blog pages that use this partial -->
{::nomarkdown}
<figure class="<%= classes %>">
  <!-- Show the image and link to the full resolution on click-->
  <a target="_blank" href="<%= src %>" >
    <img src="<%= src %>" alt="<%= alt %>">
  </a>

  <figcaption><%= caption %></figcaption>
</figure>
{:/}
```

And call this partial like so

No prefix will be added:

```
<%= partial "partials/image.erb", locals: {
    src: "/images/icons/tech/atom.svg",
    alt: "Atom",
    classes: "icon" } %>
```

Prefix will be added:

```
<%= partial "partials/image.erb", locals: {
    src: "my-lovely-dog.svg",
    alt: "Dog",
    caption: "Woof woof!",
    classes: "icon" } %>
```

I keep this partial up to date [here](https://github.com/JTronLabs/Portfolio/blob/master/source/partials/_image.erb) (in case I add/edit any of it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I ended up using, based on [this response](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/98#issuecomment-495169800) to an issue on the Kramdown repo. (Kramdown is Jekyll's markdown parser):

In a directory `_plugins` create a file called e.g. `kramdown-image-parsing.rb` containing the following...

```rb
require 'kramdown/converter/html'

module StandaloneImages
  def convert_p(el, indent)
    return super unless el.children.size == 1 && (el.children.first.type == :img || (el.children.first.type == :html_element && el.children.first.value == "img"))
    convert(el.children.first, indent)
  end
end

Kramdown::Converter::Html.prepend StandaloneImages
```

Hey presto! It works.

Answer (score 0):

I obsevered the same behavior for images and other non-blocks elements.

Adding a css-class like `handle-as-span` would create an option to change the `display` property to `inline` via css.

```markdown
{: .handle-as-span }
![Image Alt Tag](path/to/image)
```

The generated HTML

```html
<p class="handle-as-span"><img src="path/to/image" alt="Image Alt Tag" /></p>
```

Here the CSS magic

```css
p.handle-as-span {
  display: inline;
}
```