# Making Jekyll img's wider than the text?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

For my Jekyll blog, I want the images to span the whole width of the column, while having padding on either side of the text, like this: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/05/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-animation

The main problem I'm having is that Jekyll wraps images in `<p>` tags, so there's no way (that I know of) to target the width of images without and not the paragraphs.

```
<p>
  "Some text."
</p>
<p> <img src="#"> </p>
```

How would you suggest tackling this issue?

Comment: what specifically is the question then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Davids answer is really good. However, if you have no problem solving this with jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('.content > p > img').parent().css('padding','0');
```

That way your markdown will stay clean.

Comment: This is nice, and it might be what I end up using, but I find it so silly that there is not better workaround for this. I can't be the only one that wants to style images differently than paragraphs, so how can it be that markdown offers no differentiation?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you are writing your post/page in markdown.

In order to apply a specific style to the `P` container you can use [kramdown block attributes](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html) to set a class on it.

```
Some test

![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
{: .imgContainer}
```

Will render as

```
<p>Some test</p>

<p class="imgContainer"><img src="/path/to/img.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></p>
```

You can then style `.imgContainer`.

Comment: Is there really no better way to do this though? Is it really necessary to manually set a class every time I want to add an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to create an HTML block. This is done by wrapping an img tag in a div like this:

```
line

<div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>

line
```

No clean markdown, but a pretty clean solution nevertheless. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456010/in-markdown-is-there-a-way-to-stop-images-from-being-wrapped-with-p-tags).