# Jekyll post specific styling (adding images, columns of text for certain paragraphs, etc)

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I want to be able to achieve this: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1052576/screenshots/2524013/attachments/497842/loylecarnerfeature.jpg

I'm quite new to jekyll and can't find anything on here, or anywhere, that helps me. I got the full page header sorted out but can't seem to get styling in the post (white rectangle) bit properly. eg: the quote at the top having different css than the rest of the post, some bits of the post having a 2 column layout for text/images, and the background blue outline image a bit down the post. Would be great if someone could help thank you.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148026/making-jekyll-imgs-wider-than-the-text. It might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML structure should be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include menu.html %}
<div class="title">{{ page.title }}</div>
<div class="subtitle">{{ page.title }}</div>
<div class="meta">Posted on {{ page.date }} by {{ page.author }}</div>
<div class="page">{{ content }}{% include footer.html %}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your post/index.md should be something like this:

```
----
title: 'Loyle Carner: Benjamin Coyle-Larner'
subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
date: 2016-02-27
author: 'Your Name'
----

Lorem ipsum dolor...

Sit amet.
```

Your CSS should be something like this:

```
body {
  background: white url(header_image.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;   /* set header image width */
  color: black;            /* set text color */
  text-align: center;      /* make sure everything is centered */
}
.page, .title, subtitle {
  background: white;       /* set background color on text */
  display: inline-block;   /* boxes that follow text-align: center; */
}
.page {
  width: 900px;            /* fixed width of the text */
  max-width: 100%;         /* make it responsive */
  text-align: left;        /* left align text in page */
}
.meta {color: white;}
```

I hope this will give you a good starting point.