# Different widths for images and texts with Jekyll

Tags: html, css, jekyll

If the answer to my question seems obvious, please excuse me—I tried to do it myself, I searched around for a solution… and, unfortunately, I'm still stuck. :(

I am looking to set different widths for images and texts, so my blog can display large pictures while keeping a pleasant line length.

It would be easy to achieve, only if Jekyll didn't wrap all `<img>` in `<p>` tags. No matter how I change my CSS, it never does the trick.

Some time ago, I found someone's post on Stack Overflow stating that the solution is to specify a class directly in Markdown files. Like this:

`[image-1]:  {{ site.baseurl }}/images/lostcrow.jpg "A beautifully lost crow"
{: .classy }`

It didn't work, not for me at least—the class being applied to the `<img>` tag, not to the `<p>`tag:

`<p><img class="classy" src="/images/lostcrow.jpg" alt="A beautifully lost crow" title="Lost Crow" /></p>`

So the image's width is still dependent on the text's width…

Please, is there a way to set different widths for images and texts with Jekyll? I would really appreciate your guidance.

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, in both cases, I would need to set a width superior to 100% (like 120% for example) for images to reach the right size—and then, the images are not centered anymore. Also, it brings an horizontal scroll that I'd rather not have. Still open for new answers, if you feel so inclined. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Thanks to your kind help, I was able to do just what I wanted with my blog appearance. I really appreciate it.  Thank you very much, @JoostS ! <3

Comment: Also, thank you @DC.Azndj ! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative margin on the image should work:

```
.classy {margin: 0 -100px; width: calc(100% + 200px);}
```

... or just like this:

```
p img {margin: 0 -100px; width: calc(100% + 200px);}
```

... or check this post: [Making Jekyll img's wider than the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148026/making-jekyll-imgs-wider-than-the-text)

Comment: Yes, I saw you posted a solution with jQuery—but I have no JavaScript on my page, and I would really like to keep it that way. Still trying to fully understand HTML and CSS. As for the CSS solution, it works—but I'd need to go over 100% for the width, and then I can't seem to be able to center the image anymore. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have updated the answer to accomodate for your center-problem.

Comment: It works! That's really awesome of you. Many, many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how Jekyll processes Markdown + HTML, but switching from Markdown to HTML just for images is a possible solution.

[The Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameters-to-includes) have a nice example of passing parameters to the `include` tag in Jekyll. The example in the docs is similar to what I'm suggesting. You would have an `image.html` file in the `/_includes/` folder that contains the `<img>` tag, classes, and anything else you need for images. You would pass the image url or file location as a parameter to the `include` so that it would load the image with all *your* HTML instead of Jekyll processing it and adding it's own HTML. Something like the following would work:

```
# /_includes/image.html
<img src="{{ include.src }}" alt="{{ include.alt }}" title="{{ include.title }}" />


# in some other file where you want to add an image
{% include image.html src="..." alt="..." title="..." %}
```

If you're not nesting the `include` tag under any Markdown like `## header` or `- list`, Jekyll *should hopefully* just take the `image.html` and directly put it into the output without surrounding it with anything.

You could also add other parameters like `height={{ include.height }} width ={{ include.width }}` to manually set the height/width.

Worst-case scenario is switching completely from Markdown to HTML. It gives you full control of the output since Jekyll won't insert it's own wrapping tags. Switching would definitely be a hassle, but speaking from experience I definitely learned a lot writing my own blog in HTML. It definitely helped me understand how websites work and become a better web developer.

Good luck!

Comment: I thought about using includes, but I was a bit lost. Your answer helped me to get a better understanding of how this works, so thank you! :)